# Database insertion not happening

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

```
int i=0;
ContentValues values = null;

for ( SortedMap.Entry<Integer, String> entry : mapDefect.entrySet() ) {
    if( i++ < count )
        continue;
        if( i < arrlst.size() ) {
            values = new ContentValues();
            Log.d("MAP", "Id :"+entry.getKey()+"Des :"+entry.getValue()+"Co :"+ arrlst.get(i));
            values.put( MARKER_COORD, arrlst.get( i ) );
            values.put( MARKER_ID, entry.getKey() ); 
            values.put( DEFECT_DESCRIPTION, entry.getValue() );
            values.put( IMAGE_ID_F, imageID + 1 );
            Log.d( "Err", "in insertNewDefectsDescription" );
            long rowId = db.insert( TABLE_DEFECTS, null, values );
            long rowId1 = rowId;
            i++;
        }
    }
```

So, I want to access the arraylist only after the count variable, which is why the:-

```
if(i++<count)
    continue;
```

But, when I insert a break point at the 'insert' line, it is not working. The line is not executing at all, and hence the data is not being inserted into the database. What has gone wrong??

The 'values' are null.

Comment: The continue statement skips the current iteration of a for, while , or do-while loop. so if(i++<count) condition is true then your for loop iteration will finish and new iteration will start and again same condition will check

Comment: You should debug and inspect the values of `count`, `arrlist.size()` and `mapDefect.size()`. Note that your insert logic will only trip for that (narrow?) window when your index variable i is greater than `count`, but less than `arrlist.size()`.

Comment: Where is count being set? This code looks slightly shabby anyway tbh.

Comment: why don't you do `i=count` before the for loop. it would save a lot of iterations

Comment: COunt is being set much before. and the value in the count is correct.

doing i=count didn't solve the problem. some irregular issues turned up!!

Comment: alternatively i also tried if(i++>=count) and put the statements inside this if condition. the if condition is working fine (cnfirmed after debugging)

Comment: OK STARTING OFF FRESHLY:-

    The control is enterting  if( i < arrlst.size() ) at the correct moment. However the 'values' after the control enters the condition is null and in the debug mode, all the lines till i++ are skipped. Has that made it clear. THere is no problem with the i or the count variable. The arrlist and the entry all contain the correct and required values. But it is SKIPPING directly to the i++ line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is little difficult to understand
following are my suggestions

**1.why don't you do i=count before the for loop. it would save a lot of iterations**

**2. Your i may be incremented twice for example**

```
if( i++ < count ) //suppose this condition is false
```

even if the condition is false i++ happens any your i gets incremented then inside

```
if( i < arrlst.size() ) {
...
i++;// It increments i again
}
```

the logic gets wrong here

Comment: I want i to to increment till count doing nothing. and after that i is to be incremented til the end.
The logic followed with i and count seems correct. While debugging, the control is going in/out at the correct time. However the statements inside the 
if( i < arrlst.size() ) are not executed in a proper manner. the values.put stmts are not working.. the control is directly going to the i++.

Answer (score 0):

Why is it that you also have an increment in your i at the if condition? What will happen is, every iteration your i increments by two. Maybe what you want to do is initialize first your i to 1 before the loop, then you can delete the ++ in your i in the if condition or you can just delete the ++ in your i at the end of the loop.

Comment: But it didn't increment by 2. It was incrementing correctly by 1 each time. And when the condition failed, it started skipping the continue statement and started checking the next if condition. In this condition, the statements till i++ were all skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing `count` it is difficult to know the problem solution.  My guess is i++ is always less than count, thus resulting in the remainder of the loop body being skipped and the next element being inspected.  You most likely want. `if(i++>count)...`

Further it is a good practice to use curly braces `{ }` for one line `if` blocks

Comment: nope, count is correct which has been set before. and i want to skip the iteration till the 'count'th number. after which i want to start extracting the values from the arraylist and the mapentry.

Comment: @PramodSetlur can you post the full method code?  We have no way of knowing what count is.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. 
I used if and else. In the else region I incremented the i variable, and it worked fine.

```
if(i<count)
{
    ..
}
else
    i++;
```